# how to deploy django app to VPS (CentOS) from github?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django with sqlite, Now my app is on my Github and I have a VPS with CentOS. Please help me how to upload my App from Github to my VPS.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's on github, all you should need to is git clone the repo to your vps, and install django, just as you would start any django project.

If you want to do a production deploy on a CentOS server have a look at this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-centos-7 and look out for your SELinux settings, and your security in general.

Comment: "all you should need to is git clone the repo to your Vps" , I don't know what should I do. I had tried the link you sent to me but didn't get anything, I really don't have any experiences in Server

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/, this is information is widely available on the web. SSH into your vps and git clone your repository from github to your vps.

Comment: i had used this command "git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY" in terminal of my mac in the root of Vps, and it was successful. so what is the next step?

Comment: Read the digitalocean link I put in my answer, follow the appropriate steps (baring in mind that you already have a project). I'm not sure what your project is for, but if it's going to handle sensitive information it may be worthwhile hiring someone who knows how to set up a secure django server to do it for you.